# How to change cursor to pointer in my html code

Tags: html, pointers

guys, I want to change my cursor to pointer(hand) where I hover on email or password case. I know that I have to do it in my CSS but don't know which exact class should I use.
Thanks for any advice!

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-signin my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Prihlásenie</h5>
          <form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="text" name="username" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
              <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="heslo">
              <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit" value="Login!">
            <hr class="my-4">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, `input` fields (email, password) has got `form-control` class.
So you can define `cursor: pointer` css attribute to change cursor to pointer on `.form-control:hover` (on hover action).

```css
.form-control:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-signin my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">Prihlásenie</h5>
          <form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="text" name="username" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
              <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="heslo">
              <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit" value="Login!">
            <hr class="my-4">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: On which browser, are you testing?

Comment: I am on chrome and it is working well... `cursor` css attribute works on nearly all browsers except android webview and android firefox

Comment: When i try to run code snippet on your code here,  it works..But on my goorm server where im creating my web app not:/

Comment: Is it live site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223049/discussion-between-derek-w-and-dominik-smolinsky).